# PHP explode all square bracket

Tags: php, regex

how do i explode the square brackets and then replace them with some text?

i tried the following code, but it seems only recognize the first two:

Regex code:

```
/(\[[\w\s]+\])/g
```

anyone can suggest what needs to be changed in the regex code?

```
$data = "[Foo Bar],[Suganthan],['Test1',1,5.09,12.50, 7.41]";

but it only finds: [Foo Bar],[Suganthan]

preg_replace('/(\[[\w\s]+\])/', 'replaced', $data);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex to capture all the square bracket contents:

```
(\[[^]]+\])
```

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fR4cG3/2)

**Code:**

```
$data = preg_replace('/\[[^]]+\]/', 'replaced', $data);
```

If you only want to find content from inside the `[` and `]` then use **lookarounds** as in this regex:

```
(?<=\[)[^]]+(?=\])
```

And use code as:

```
$data = preg_replace('/(?<=\[)[^]]+(?=\])/', 'replaced', $data);
```

Answer (score 5):

That is because you're limiting the matchable characters in character class. `[\w\s]+` only matchs all alphanumericals and spaces and underscore.

Use  `[^]]+`

which means match anything *except* `]`

Answer (score 3):

```
/(\[.*?\])/g
```

You can try this.Your regex will not match `['Test1',1,5.09,12.50, 7.41]` this wont match as it has `,` and `'` which are not convered by `\w\s`

Or simply use

```
(\[[\w\s',.]+\])
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/rU8yP6/23